# how to cut drive name from given path in python

Tags: python

In python I want to cut the drive name from given path,

```
Example:
if path given is D:\John\myfolder\newfolder
then I should get John\myfolder\newfolder
```

please tell how can I do this? I am trying to use os.path.abspath(path) but this is not working...

Answer (score 4):

With [`os.path.splitdrive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive):

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: drive, tail = os.path.splitdrive(r'D:\John\myfolder\newfolder')

In [3]: tail
Out[3]: '\\John\\myfolder\\newfolder'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use slicing.

```
>>> path = r"D:\John\myfolder\newfolder"
>>> print(path[3:])
John\myfolder\newfolder
```